# How do I detect more than one gesture on a single widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to listen for tap events on a widget and take one action for that, and a hold event and take a different action for that. It looks like flutter gesture detector can only detect a single gesture? This seems like it would be hugely limiting for mobile development though, so I figured there must be a way to detect two different gestures on one widget. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you see the api docs, you will see there are detectors like doubletap, longpress etc
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html

Comment: Thanks! My bad, I misread the API docs and thought I could only populate one callback.